# Correct way to do HTTP.PUT

Tags: java, maven, http, curl, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to do `HTTP.PUT` from my maven plugin to a target server:

```
private void uploadFile(Wagon wagon, String fileName, Artifact artifact) throws MojoExecutionException {
    if (artifact != null) {
        try {
            //org.apache.maven.wagon
            wagon.put(artifact.getFile(), fileName);

        } catch (TransferFailedException | ResourceDoesNotExistException | AuthorizationException e) {
            throw new MojoExecutionException("failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Request

```
PUT /somepath/myfile.bla HTTP/1.1
Cache-control: no-cache
Cache-store: no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer xxx
Content-Length: 123
Host: targethost
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.5 (java 1.5)
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.12.1
Date: Thu, 31 Aug 2017 11:45:18 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 69
Connection: keep-alive
```

This seems totally legit to me, but it fails with 404 as you see. The maintainer of the *targethost* is telling me that the file name must not be contained in the path and indeed, if I do it with cURL:

```
curl -v -X PUT -T myfile.bla https://targethost/somepath -H "Authorization: Bearer .." --Capath /path/to -k
```

it results in:

```
> PUT /somepath HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: targethost
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer ...
> Content-Length: 123
> Expect: 100-continue
```

Am failing to do the PUT as the maintainer of *targethost* requires. I've also tried

```
File file = artifact.getFile();
((HttpWagon) wagon).putFromStream(new FileInputStream(file), fileName, file.length(), file.lastModified());
```

but the outcome is the same. Any hints?

Comment: did you try `wagon.put(artifact.getFile(), fileName);` but instead of the `filename==targethost/somepath/myfile.bla` use `filename==targethost/somepath/` ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I simply removed the destination from putToStream call and it works as expected now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was to remove the destination from `putFromStream` call:

```
((HttpWagon) wagon).putFromStream(new FileInputStream(file), "", file.length(), file.lastModified());
```